# How to add query params to route in guard and pass it to component in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am using a route guard in my angular 4 app, and I would like to add a query param to the route if a condition satisfies and return true.

Here's the code I have been working on

```
@Injectable()
export class ViewGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(activatedRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, snapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(!this.router.url.includes('/order-management')) {
      //ADD PARAMS TO ROUTE OR PASS DATA TO COMPONENT HERE AND THEN RETURN TRUE
       return true;
    } else {
       this.route.navigate['/login'];
       return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Usually, to navigate to a route with params we can use it as `this.router.navigate(['/order-management', activatedRoute.url[0].path], { queryParams: { moveToOrders: true }});`. But if I use this condition in the `if` condition, it turns out to an infinite loop of function calls.

So how do I pass params or data from the guard to the component? Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Hello Proton Starlight, did you find an answer to that ? I need the same thing and i can't find any answer on that since this morning

Comment: @MartinStievenart I couldn't find any solution for that. But a small hack worked for me. If the condition is `true`, set the data you need in `localStorage` or `ngrx` State, and retrieve it in the component you need.

Comment: Ok, it's not technically what i need to achieve, i need to pass a query string parameters in every page if it's present at one point. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit hacky, but it works (Angular 11).

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SetQueryParamGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    const requiredQueryParam = route.queryParamMap.get('requiredQueryParam');

    // Query param is set, no further action
    if (requiredQueryParam) {
      return of(true);
    }

    return of(
               this._router
                   .parseUrl(state.url + `&requiredQueryParam=DEFAULT_VALUE`)
    );        
  }
}
```